Why is my dropdown not showing when hovered
I'm trying to get the dropdown on the  #Section31 to appear when hovered and it is not working either it is not showing or it shows even when it is not hovered.
I tried to change the .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu { and all of the display: properties but none of changes is working as intended


.Dropdown {
  display: none;
}

ul li ul.dropdown {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>HK Kraso Nitra</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="NewLogoMain.png" type="image/png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="HeaderContainer">
    <div class="LogoContainer">
      <img src="NewLogoMain.png" alt="Main Logo" class="MainLogoHeader">
    </div>
    <nav class="MarkContainer">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#HomeSection1">Domov</a></li>
        <li><a href="#onas">O klube</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#Section31">Skupiny</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tréningy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eventy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Obchod</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>




You don't need to hide the li's inside the ul.dropdown-menu

Your display in the drop-down menu and the position need some refactoring
Remove the display: none; from .dropdown-menu li
and make some changes to the class reference
Updated Code


ul li {
  position: relative;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  display: block; /* Changed from none to block */
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<header class="HeaderContainer">
  <div class="LogoContainer">
    <img src="NewLogoMain.png" alt="Main Logo" class="MainLogoHeader">
  </div>
  <nav class="MarkContainer">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#HomeSection1">Domov</a></li>
      <li><a href="#onas">O klube</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#Section31">Skupiny</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Tréningy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Eventy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Obchod</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>




You can just remove .dropdown-menu li { display: block; /* Changed from none to block */ } and then it will use the default style display list-item, and also it's less css
